# Normal cpu usage when browsing

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

Just a quick question.
What's the normal cpu usage when you are browsing the web no video or audio only text for the raspberry pi 3B.

Because everytime i start Chromium the cpu usage jumps to 70% and after 5 sec it goes back to 5% or less. Is this normal or is somethin wrong with my pi? This also happends with other programs on my pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Raspberry PI, but Chromium & Chrome are known for their cpu usage in all other platfroms & machines. (Chromium uses many process in comparison with Firefox by example). I guess that you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: But should it really go up to 70% cpu usage just by opening it. Even on harder task like watching videos it stays at 20%

Comment: @Aheagle, yes initialising all browser's components  seem to be more complex than just reading frames from a video file and rendering them for Chromium. In one of my old PC (with better performance than any Raspberry), watching a video can be fast and less CPU consuming than browsing the web (with Chromium and Firefox).

Comment: In your case, you may prefer to use browsers with less complexity, in your place, I would use nw.js as browser. (take a look also to Servo browser by Mozilla)

Comment: Ok but is it also normal when i open python i also get those cpu jumps?

Comment: Does the CPU jump every time you run Python? or just with some script?

Comment: Right now the cpu only jumps when im starting chromium and my script . But i just want to know if its normal that it does jump sometimes to high cpu levels

Comment: I don't think that terminal a lot cpu ressources. I guess that your cpu don't have any problem. First, for chromium this is normal. for your script, if you're trying to do some artificiel intelligence or neural network (in python) that may be normal (even best desktop available in the market will fail with AI). also if you'r doing a lot of matrix multiplication may also cause the cpu jumps.